# SSH no colors until running bash

Tags: bash, terminal

When I ssh into another machine, all text is colored white. 
However, when I run the cmd "bash" I get colored output.

`echo $0` outputs "-bash".

After running the command "bash" and changing to colored output
`echo $0` outputs "bash" without "-".

How can I get colored bash as standard when I ssh into other machines without having to use the command "bash" and exit x2 to disconnect.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/546761/how-do-i-start-in-bash-when-sshing-into-my-server

Comment: The reason why the text is not colored before you call bash is probably that the coloring is set in a bash start script like `.bashrc`.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332531/why-does-remote-bash-source-bash-profile-instead-of-bashrc

Comment: Run the following command before and after the "bash" command and compare the result:

`echo $TERM`

If the TERM setting changes this can be the setting to enables the colored output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the remote machine, make sure you have a  `.bash_profile`, `bash_login`, or `.profile` file in your home directory. There should only be one of those files, but if there are more than one, use the first from that list. At a minimum, that file should include the line:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

You should then see the colors as soon as you log in to the remote machine.